# google maps return all nearest saved long lat in my database

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel, latitude-longitude

I would like to ask how can I get the nearest long lat(saved locations) on my database base on my current location lets say when I click search it will get my current location via google maps API and it will search 50kilometers around current location to my database which I saved many locations that has a long lat.

Comment: you're looking for spatial queries. you can go the accurate way using GeomFromText (mysql) or just a plain rectangle where ou add x degrees to the long lat locations.

Comment: What are you having difficulty with specifically, and what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn’t really the place to get professional programmers to write solutions for you. Try breaking the problem down into smaller, manageable tasks and tackle them that way.

Comment: @martinBean thanks I am fully aware of that. Im if there is already an existing API for this on google which I can't find on my own research. im not looking for a programmer to do the task. Im just asking for reference which I can look up to. Thanks (y)

Comment: @zwacky thanks for the reference. this could be a good start..